# Android XML layouts cant inverse items in layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have portrait layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frag_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <fragment 
       android:name="com.example.appmenager.fragments.AllAppsFragment"
        android:id="@+id/applistview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and landscape layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frag_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/applistview"
        android:name="com.example.appmenager.fragments.AllAppsFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragViewPage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But when i swap FrameLayout with fragment like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frag_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragViewPage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/applistview"
        android:name="com.example.appmenager.fragments.AllAppsFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />




</LinearLayout>
```

I get Error:

> 05-02 08:17:59.000: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.appmenager/com.example.appmenager.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.appmenager.fragments.AllAppsFragment cannot be cast to
>   com.example.appmenager.fragments.WebViewFragment

So whats is wrong? And how I can swap elements of layout safely?

PS

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebViewFragment webViewFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            if (findViewById(R.id.applistview) != null) {
            }
        }

        if (this.getResources()
                .getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            if (findViewById(R.id.fragViewPage) != null) {
                webViewFragment = (WebViewFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.fragViewPage);
                System.out.println("Get fragView");
                if (webViewFragment == null) {
                    System.out.println("Dual fragment - 1");
                    webViewFragment = new WebViewFragment();
                    webViewFragment.init("https://www.google.com");

                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                    ft.replace(R.id.fragViewPage, webViewFragment);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

AllAppsFragment

```
public class AllAppsFragment extends ListFragment {
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;
    private HashMap<ApplicationInfo, Float> appRating = null;
    private SharedPreferences sh = null;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = null;
    public static final String MY_PREFERENCES = "myPreferences";

    private Button sortLex = null;
    private Button sortLexDesc = null;
    private Button sortRating = null;
    private Button sortRatingDesc = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         * Inflate the layout for this fragment
         */
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_apps_listview, container, false);
        sortLex = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.sortlex_button);
        sortLexDesc = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.sortlexdesc_button);
        sortRating = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.sortrating_button);
        sortRatingDesc = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.sortratingdesc_button);


        sortLex.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listadaptor.sortLex();
            }
        });
        sortLexDesc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listadaptor.sortLexDesc();
            }
        });
        sortRating.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listadaptor.sortRating();
            }
        });


        sortRatingDesc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listadaptor.sortRaingDesc();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setRetainInstance(true);
         setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        packageManager = getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageManager();

        ProgressDialog loader = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        loader.setTitle("Ładujemy!");
        new LoadApplications(getActivity(),loader).execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(
            List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog progress = null;
        private final WeakReference<Activity> mainActivityWeakRef;
        Activity a;

        public LoadApplications() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.mainActivityWeakRef = null;
        }

        public LoadApplications(Activity MainActivity) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.mainActivityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(MainActivity);
            this.a = MainActivity;
        }

        public LoadApplications(Activity activity, ProgressDialog loader) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.mainActivityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
            this.a = activity;
            this.progress = loader;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager
                    .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(getActivity()
                    .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.app_row_item,
                    applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            sh = getActivity().getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(
                    MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int sortOrder = sh.getInt("sort_type", 0);
            switch (sortOrder) {
            case 1:
                listadaptor.sortLex();
                break;
            case 2:
                listadaptor.sortLexDesc();
                break;

            case 3:
                listadaptor.sortRating();
                break;

            case 4:
                listadaptor.sortRaingDesc();
                break;

            default:
            }

            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your fragment is a AllAppsFragment which cannot be cast to WebViewFragment. It would be helpful if you post the AllAppsFragment code here because it doesn't look like an layout error but rather like a cast error in your MainActivity.

Comment: AllAppsFragment extends ListFragment, which extends Fragment
WebViewFragment also extends Fragment. You cannot cast from the one to the other.